# undefined method `count' for Application:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first time playing with Rails and I'm getting the following error...

```
undefined method `count' for Application:Class
```

My controller looks like this...

```
class AvabotController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

    def index
        text = params[:text].split(' ')

        if text[0] == 'count'
            response = Application.count
        end

        render plain: response
    end
end
```

And my Application model...

```
class Application < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Why am I getting this error? It was working before but now it's not!

*Edit
If I swap out Application with any of my other active record models (e.g. Location) it works just fine.

Comment: It's quite obvious. `count` method does not exist.

Comment: If I swap out Application with any of my other active record models it works just fine.

Comment: @NickM Yes. It's a rails 5 app

Comment: `It was working before but now it's not!` When it was working?

Comment: Did you change something in ApplicationRecord? Can you post it?

Comment: if you puts text (before split) what you get? `puts params[:text]`

Answer (score 0):

Could you look for the true nature of the "Application" element you call in your controller?
`text[0] == 'count'
 response = Application.count
 end`

and compare it with one of your models. I'm not sure, but "Application" may be reserved for something else in the context of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to count there, but `Application.count` doesn't make too much sense to mee. If you're trying to count the objects for the model in the current controller, you could do something like:

```
if params[:controller]
  params[:controller].classify.constantize.try(:count) || 0
end
```

So, in that way, it won't throw an error when the model doesn't exists... it will return 0